# Seperate column into two sections inside a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors and I want to create a table that compares the expected value and variance (of gamma distribution).

```
a <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)
b <- c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5,10,100)
q3 <- matrix(NA,
             nrow=7,
             ncol=7,
             dimnames=list(
             (colnames=a),
             (rownames=b)
                )
                )
for(m in 1:7)
{
  for(n in 1:7)
  {
    q3[m,n]<-paste((a[m]/b[n]),(a[m]/b[n]^2))
  }
}
as.data.frame(q3)
```

This gives

```
           0.1     0.5       1          2          5         10         100
0.1       1 10 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.025 0.02 0.004 0.01 0.001 0.001 1e-05
0.5       5 50     1 2 0.5 0.5 0.25 0.125   0.1 0.02 0.05 0.005 0.005 5e-05
1       10 100     2 4     1 1   0.5 0.25   0.2 0.04   0.1 0.01  0.01 1e-04
2       20 200     4 8     2 2      1 0.5   0.4 0.08   0.2 0.02  0.02 2e-04
5       50 500   10 20     5 5   2.5 1.25      1 0.2   0.5 0.05  0.05 5e-04
10    100 1000   20 40   10 10      5 2.5      2 0.4      1 0.1   0.1 0.001
100 1000 10000 200 400 100 100      50 25       20 4       10 1      1 0.01
```

I was looking to label each column inside the columns as E(x) and Var(x) while still keeping the columnnames, I'm not sure if this is actually possible or if I should just take a different approach.
edit:

```
 E(x)V(x)0.1 E(x)V(x)0.5 E(x)V(x)1 E(x)V(x)2 E(x)V(x)5 E(x)V(x)10 E(x)V(x)100
0.1       1 10 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.05 0.025 0.02 0.004 0.01 0.001 0.001 1e-05
0.5       5 50     1 2 0.5 0.5 0.25 0.125   0.1 0.02 0.05 0.005 0.005 5e-05
1       10 100     2 4     1 1   0.5 0.25   0.2 0.04   0.1 0.01  0.01 1e-04
2       20 200     4 8     2 2      1 0.5   0.4 0.08   0.2 0.02  0.02 2e-04
5       50 500   10 20     5 5   2.5 1.25      1 0.2   0.5 0.05  0.05 5e-04
10    100 1000   20 40   10 10      5 2.5      2 0.4      1 0.1   0.1 0.001
100 1000 10000 200 400 100 100      50 25       20 4       10 1      1 0.01
```

This is what I would like it to look like, I know I could just change the columnnames but I want each column to be assigned to E(x) etc.

Do I need to make a data frame with twice as many columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer` for this

```
m1 <- outer(a, b, FUN =  function(x, y) paste(x/y, x/y^2))
dimnames(m1) <- list(row.names(q3), paste0("E(x)V(x) ", colnames(q3)))
as.data.frame(m1)
#    E(x)V(x) 0.1 E(x)V(x) 0.5 E(x)V(x) 1 E(x)V(x) 2 E(x)V(x) 5 E(x)V(x) 10 E(x)V(x) 100
#0.1         1 10      0.2 0.4    0.1 0.1 0.05 0.025 0.02 0.004  0.01 0.001  0.001 1e-05
#0.5         5 50          1 2    0.5 0.5 0.25 0.125   0.1 0.02  0.05 0.005  0.005 5e-05
#1         10 100          2 4        1 1   0.5 0.25   0.2 0.04    0.1 0.01   0.01 1e-04
#2         20 200          4 8        2 2      1 0.5   0.4 0.08    0.2 0.02   0.02 2e-04
#5         50 500        10 20        5 5   2.5 1.25      1 0.2    0.5 0.05   0.05 5e-04
#10      100 1000        20 40      10 10      5 2.5      2 0.4       1 0.1    0.1 0.001
#100   1000 10000      200 400    100 100      50 25       20 4        10 1       1 0.01
```

Comment: I was looking for it to just say E(x) and Var(x) at the top of each column instead of for each entry.

Comment: Is sprintf different to paste? I have not seen this

Comment: @user100000 i was looking at the other answer and coded.  So, i thought it is what you wanted

Comment: @user100000 not very different, but it is flexible to use that in this case

Comment: @user100000 when you say top of the column, is it the first row?

Comment: I wanted it to be a part of the column names because I thought it would not be aligned properly if it was in it's own row

Comment: @user100000 can you please update your post with expected output.  In your code, it is doing a double nested loop.  So, the length would be m x n.

Comment: @user100000 i updated the solution.  Hope it is the one you wanted

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply improve you paste() function call like this:

```
for(m in 1:7)
{
  for(n in 1:7)
  {
    q3[m,n]<-paste("E(x)=", a[m]/b[n], "Var(x)=", a[m]/b[n]^2)
  }
}
as.data.frame(q3)
```

Output

```
                         0.1                   0.5                     1                        2
0.1       E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 10 E(x)= 0.2 Var(x)= 0.4 E(x)= 0.1 Var(x)= 0.1 E(x)= 0.05 Var(x)= 0.025
0.5       E(x)= 5 Var(x)= 50     E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 2 E(x)= 0.5 Var(x)= 0.5 E(x)= 0.25 Var(x)= 0.125
1       E(x)= 10 Var(x)= 100     E(x)= 2 Var(x)= 4     E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 1   E(x)= 0.5 Var(x)= 0.25
2       E(x)= 20 Var(x)= 200     E(x)= 4 Var(x)= 8     E(x)= 2 Var(x)= 2      E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 0.5
5       E(x)= 50 Var(x)= 500   E(x)= 10 Var(x)= 20     E(x)= 5 Var(x)= 5   E(x)= 2.5 Var(x)= 1.25
10    E(x)= 100 Var(x)= 1000   E(x)= 20 Var(x)= 40   E(x)= 10 Var(x)= 10      E(x)= 5 Var(x)= 2.5
100 E(x)= 1000 Var(x)= 10000 E(x)= 200 Var(x)= 400 E(x)= 100 Var(x)= 100      E(x)= 50 Var(x)= 25
                           5                       10                       100
0.1 E(x)= 0.02 Var(x)= 0.004 E(x)= 0.01 Var(x)= 0.001 E(x)= 0.001 Var(x)= 1e-05
0.5   E(x)= 0.1 Var(x)= 0.02 E(x)= 0.05 Var(x)= 0.005 E(x)= 0.005 Var(x)= 5e-05
1     E(x)= 0.2 Var(x)= 0.04   E(x)= 0.1 Var(x)= 0.01  E(x)= 0.01 Var(x)= 1e-04
2     E(x)= 0.4 Var(x)= 0.08   E(x)= 0.2 Var(x)= 0.02  E(x)= 0.02 Var(x)= 2e-04
5        E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 0.2   E(x)= 0.5 Var(x)= 0.05  E(x)= 0.05 Var(x)= 5e-04
10       E(x)= 2 Var(x)= 0.4      E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 0.1   E(x)= 0.1 Var(x)= 0.001
100       E(x)= 20 Var(x)= 4       E(x)= 10 Var(x)= 1      E(x)= 1 Var(x)= 0.01
```

The problem with this form is that it is not treatable. It is only good for display of output. The ideal is to keep values as entities, either having their own columns or in the [tidy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) format.

So a better idea would be to create columns E(0.1), E(0.5), ... and Var(0.1), Var(0.5), etc or some other naming you might like. It would save space in your output and keep the columns treatable.

Comment: I did try this earlier but I just felt it didn't look good, so yes I will try something with changing the column names, Thanks